# Scaling iPhone game to iPad using Xcode & SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit

Swift
SpriteKit
Ive my "scenes" set up at a size of 2208x1242 & it plays in landscape.
It plays perfectly on my iPhone 6s plus & also on an iPhone 5.

However, on the 9.7" iPad it displays only a part of the screen & a part from right & left sides is outside the screen when in landscape. It also plays in portrait which makes things worse.

How do I make my game fit for iPad without changing my scene size?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you're using `.AspectFill` as your `sceneScaleMode`. Now, since you're getting this blank part of the scene only on iPad, you should make the background nodes have a larger width than the scene width. This is because on iPhone you don't need the back ground to be stretched wider (almost to or to square), whereas on iPad you need the full width. After this, you'll need to make your HUD on iPad push out to the edges (I assume). To do this simply change the positions of the nodes only when the device is iPad.

As for the problem where your scene plays in portrait on iPad, do this. Go to your **info.plist** and you'll see an array of `supportedOrientations`. In that array, there should be only the wanted orientations (delete the ones you don't want). Underneath this array you'll see another similar array of orientations for iPads. Simply delete the orientations that you don't want to support on iPads.